What changed in std::begin,std::end between g++11 and g++13
This is probably a dumb question. But I noticed that this line was not compiling on one om my machines and the only diff was the version of g++ that was installed.  I updated the version back to 11 and it started working again. I don't see anything wrong with this.  Could I get some help with this?
char shipLetters[] = { 'A', 'B', 'S', 'C', 'D' };

This works in g++11, but not in g++13
char seletion;
cin >> selection;
index = std::find(begin(shipLetters), end(shipLetters), selection);


Added runnable example.
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
  char shipLetters[] = { 'A', 'B', 'S', 'C', 'D' };
  char selection;
  cin >> selection;
  char *index = std::find(begin(shipLetters), end(shipLetters), selection);
  cout << index << endl;
  return 0;
}


What headers do you include? Also, the C-array versions aren't findable by ADL for arrays of fundamental types.

Please post a [mre] and the verbatim error as a text in a code block. The currently shown code raises cin and selection are undefined at cin >> selection;.

Added an example.

It looks like I just needed to include algorithm explicitly. I am not sure why this did not error when running g++11, but it is now working.
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
int main() {
  char shipLetters[] = { 'A', 'B', 'S', 'C', 'D' };
  char selection;
  cin >> selection;
  char *index = std::find(begin(shipLetters), end(shipLetters), selection);
  cout << index << endl;
  return 0;
}

